# Binding image src in angular 2

Tags: angular

How to properly bind an img src in Angular 2?

This is my html

```
<img src ='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("{{name['_id'].path}}")' class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
```

But instead of displaying the image, it just print the string

```
<img src ='sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("E:\projects\p_cheats2\dist\server\controllers\uploads\photo-1509698091986.png")' class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
```

In ideas?

Comment: add a method and return the same , and you will not require it for images inside your app folder , it is generally used for third party images

Comment: Need to add sanitizer because it complains  unsafe net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: Have you tried using `[src]='...'`?

Comment: =as you are trying to use the drive path where as use a relative path to the image file

Comment: I am saving the path name in database like this paths = req.file.path . So the I am getting the full drive path. Maybe I missing something when saving the path name to database

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll post this as an answer.

Html

```
<img [src]="getBackground()" class="rounded mx-auto d-block">
```

TS

```
getBackGround() {
  // you may need domSanitizer here
  return name['_id'].path;
}
```

I hope it works for you.